# can i used set instead of some keyword

Tags: alloy

How to write 'set' instead of 'some' keyword in following predicate

```
pred foreward [rov: Robot, d: Direction, t,t': Time] {
-- preconditions  
   -- rover is on
   is_on[rov, t]

   -- d is rover's direction
   rov.dir.t = d
   let np = next_pos[rov.pos.t, d] | {
     -- precondition
     some np              //<-------------   here changes are needed
     --postcondition
     rov.pos.t' = np
   }

-- frame conditions
   -- all rovers stay on or off as they were
   no_on_changes[Robot, t, t']
  -- No rover changes direction  
   no_direction_changes[Robot, t, t']
   -- No other rover changes position
   no_position_changes[Robot - rov, t, t']
}
```

Comment: Please be more explicit; what is wrong with the current specification and why would you like to change some to set ? 

The some keyword enforces that there's at least one np. As Peter said in his answer, you do not need to specify that there can be any number of np because this holds by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `# np >= 0` then that is always true isn't it since you cannot have a negative number of np's?